# VBA: to calculate Monthly Returns from Daily Values

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns, Date and Daily Return. I have ~7000 daily returns, and I want to group them by their compounded return for each month of each year.

I created a VBA function to solve this:

```
Function MonthlyRet(YearNum, MonthNum, DateData, RetData) As Double
Dim nValues As Integer
nValues = DateData.Rows.Count

MonthlyRet = 1
For i = 2 To nValues
    If (IsNumeric(RetData(i)) And Year(DateData(i)) = YearNum And Month(DateData(i)) = MonthNum) Then
        MonthlyRet = MonthlyRet * RetData(i)
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

I can run this on my data using:

```
=MonthlyRet(2015,1,Data!$A$1:$A$7000,Data!$AR$1:$AR$7000)-1
```

This would return the compounded return for Jan 2015 in my dataset. This seems to work, however, when I copy and paste the equation to all months from 1990 to 2015, around 300 cells, it takes quite a long time to complete the operation on a fast computer.

The algorithm is looping 300 times through 7000 if statements. That does not seem to be that many iterations to me, but my computer will take a minute or two to calculate them all. In java I know the results would be milliseconds, but I am a VBA-novice.

Is there any way to improve the performance of this routine in VBA?

Comment: Read the ranges into vba arrays; and do the work referring to the array.  MUCH faster than multiple worksheet reads.  You read into the array in a single step:  e.g:  `Dim V1 as Variant: V1 = DateData`.  Also, you may benefit from disabling auto-calculation

Comment: This sounds like what I need. I don't think I understand how each iterative cell would reference the array with the data. Mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: See my answer  below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote above, when using VBA to look at a large range, it is better to read that range into an array, and then go through the array.  Modifying your UDF; and also **explicitly declaring** all variables and data types -- always a good thing in VBA, we wind up with:

---

```
Option Explicit
Function MonthlyRet(YearNum As Long, MonthNum As Long, DateData As Range, RetData As Range) As Double
Dim vDates As Variant, vReturns As Variant
Dim I As Long
Dim D As Double

vDates = DateData
vReturns = RetData

D = 1
For I = 2 To UBound(vDates, 1)
    If (IsDate(vDates(I, 1)) And Year(vDates(I, 1)) = YearNum And Month(vDates(I, 1)) = MonthNum) Then
        D = D * vReturns(I, 1)
    End If
Next I
MonthlyRet = D
End Function
```

---

**However**, I would suggest you look at a **Pivot Table**.  It seems to me that would be ideal for displyaing your data.  For example, you could drag the dates to the rows area; the returns data to the columns area; change the Value Field settings to Product; and then group the rows by Month and Year -- you would wind up with a nice table that would show the same results.

As an aside, I'm not sure your algorithm returns the value you are expecting. Not sure if it would be easier to use the Pivot or the UDF, once you get that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve performance. What are your limits?

### Option 1: Stick to VBA UDF

If you just want to just enhance the VBA performance of your UDF, I don't see much you can do. These changes might slightly help :

```
Function MonthlyRet(YearNum, MonthNum, DateData, RetData) As Double
   Dim nValues As Integer, i as Integer:nValues = DateData.Rows.Count:MonthlyRet = 1
   For i = 2 To nValues
     If (IsNumeric(RetData(i)) And Year(DateData(i)) = YearNum And Month(DateData(i)) = MonthNum) Then MonthlyRet = MonthlyRet * RetData(i)
   Next i
End Function
```

I wrote a post on improving VBA performance [here](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/).

### Option 2: Excel XLL UDF based functions

Excel XLL will enable multithreading for your UDF functions. A nice video here:
See more here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2ALSgK1LLY

### Option 3: Write a VBA macro and run it manually instead of using a UDF function

I would personally go with this option as `(a)` It will give you more control over when the functions refresh and prevent thus "freezing Excel" and `(b)` This will run slightly faster than separate UDF functions.